# The diophantine equation X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2 = +- 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

Hi everybody. I'd like to know if the diophantine equation

(1) $$X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2 = \pm 1$$

has been studied and if the set of its solutions $(X,Y,Z)$ is known. I appreciate any reference. Thank you very much.

P.S. If instead we look at the diophantine equation

$$X^2 - Y^2 - Z^4 = \pm 1$$

surely we can solve it imposing conditions on the solution of (1) so that Z be a square. However, is there a quicker method?

Comment: This is an old question, but in case someone else comes across it, we have the identity $$(289p^4+14p^2q^2-239q^4)^2-(17p^2-12pq-13q^2)^4 -(17p^2+12pq-13q^2)^4 = -1$$ where $p,q$ solve the _Pell equation_, $$q^2-17p^2=-1$$ So we can actually make both the $Y,Z$ of your first eqn as squares.

Answer (score 12):

In general, if $Q(x,y,z)$ is a nonsingular ternary quadratic form with integral coefficients, then the integral solutions of $Q(x,y,z)=n$ fall into finitely many orbits of the integral automorphism group of $Q$, and these orbits can be effectively determined. For your case there is a shortcut as follows.

Write $a=x+y$, $c=x-y$, $b=z$, then your equation becomes $b^2-ac=\mp 1$. In the language of binary quadratic forms, this means that the form $au^2+2buv+cv^2$ has discriminant $\mp 4$. From classical theory it follows that after an invertible linear change of variables $u'=pu+qv$, $v'=ru+sv$ the form becomes $u'^2\pm v'^2$, i.e. there are $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ps-qr=1$ and
$$ au^2+2buv+cv^2=(pu+qv)^2\pm(ru+sv)^2. $$
Equating coefficients,
$$ a=p^2\pm r^2,\quad c=q^2\pm s^2,\quad b=pq\pm rs, $$
i.e. 
$$ x=(p^2\pm r^2+q^2\pm s^2)/2,\quad y=(p^2\pm r^2-q^2\mp s^2)/2,\quad z=pq\pm rs. $$
To summarize, all integer solutions of $x^2-y^2-z^2=\pm 1$ are of this form, with integers $p,q,r,s$ satisfying $ps-qr=1$. Using congruences one can easily distinguish integer solutions from half-integer ones.

As references, I suggest Rose: A course in number theory, and Cassels: Rational quadratic forms.

Comment: @GH Thank you! Your answer is very helpful. I have added a P.S. to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is also true that the automorphism group of the quadratic form is known. See [Is there a topograph for Pythagorean triples?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110956/is-there-a-topograph-for-pythagorean-triples) 
and the three matrices. If you have any particular $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = n,$ write $(x,y,z)$ as a column vector. Multiply by any of the three square matrices or its inverse and you get another solution for $n.$  Multiply again you get another, and so on for any combination of group elements.

I see, for your ordering you need to switch first and last elements to use these three matrices.